# How to make JPasswordField render with the same length of different platforms

Tags: kotlin, swing

I am developing a cross-platform desktop app with Swing on a Windows machine and I have a `JPasswordField` in a login form. It works fine on Windows, but when I run the same jar file on a Mac, the password field renders wider than the other fields. How can I make it look the same on Windows and Mac?

This is what it looks like on windows:
[image]

And this is what it looks like on a Mac:[image]

Here is the code for the custom password field.

```
class PasswordTextField : JPasswordField(39) {
    private var hidePassword = true
    private val eyeIcon: SVGDocument
    private val eyeSlashIcon: SVGDocument

    companion object {
        private const val BORDER_RADIUS = 24
        private const val ICON_SIZE = 18.toFloat()
        private const val LABEL_TEXT = "Password"
    }

    init {
        isOpaque = false
        border = EmptyBorder(24, 16, 8, 33)
        foreground = Colors.TEXT_SECONDARY
        caretColor = Colors.TEXT_SECONDARY
        font = Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18)
        eyeIcon = requireNotNull(Icons.getEyeIcon())
        eyeSlashIcon = requireNotNull(Icons.getEyeSlashIcon())

        // Setup a hover listener for the show icon
        addMouseMotionListener(object : MouseMotionAdapter() {
            override fun mouseMoved(e: MouseEvent?) {
                val x = width - 33
                cursor = if (e != null && Rectangle(x, 20, 18, 20).contains(e.point)) {
                    Cursors.HAND
                } else {
                    Cursors.TEXT
                }
            }
        })

        // Set up a click listener for the show icon
        addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() {
            override fun mousePressed(e: MouseEvent?) {
                val x = width - 33
                if (e != null && Rectangle(x, 0, 18, 30).contains(e.point)) {
                    hidePassword = !hidePassword
                    echoChar = if (hidePassword) {
                        font = Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18)
                        0x2022.toChar()
                    } else {
                        font = Font("Poppins", Font.PLAIN, 14)
                        0.toChar()
                    }

                    repaint()
                }
            }
        })
    }


    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        val g2 = g as Graphics2D
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
        // Paint the component
        g2.color = Colors.TEXTBOX_FILL
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, BORDER_RADIUS, BORDER_RADIUS)
        createShowHideIcon(g2)

        createLabelText(g2)

        super.paintComponent(g)
    }

    private fun createShowHideIcon(g2: Graphics2D) {
        val x = (width - 30).toFloat()
        val y = ((height - 16) / 2).toFloat()
        if (hidePassword) {
            eyeSlashIcon.render(this, g2, ViewBox(x, y, ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE))
        } else {
            eyeIcon.render(this, g2, ViewBox(x, y, ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE))
        }
    }

    private fun createLabelText(g2: Graphics2D) {
        g2.color = Colors.TEXT_MAIN
        g2.font = Font("Poppins", Font.PLAIN, 14)
        val ft = g2.fontMetrics
        val r2 = ft.getStringBounds(LABEL_TEXT, g2)

        val height = height.toDouble() - insets.top - insets.bottom
        val textY = ((height - r2.height) / 2.0) - 20
        val size = 2

        g2.drawString(LABEL_TEXT, insets.right - 16, (insets.top + textY + ft.ascent - size).toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the border border setup in the init?

Comment: Im' not familar with Kotlin, but in Swing the LayoutManager is responsible for the width of a field. So you probably look for a bug on a wrong place.